# XML XSD Validation Error

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have the following XSD

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
           xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Product">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="ProductColor" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
        <xs:element name="ProductID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element name="ProductName"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ProductNumber"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ProductPrice"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am validating the following XML with that XSD

```
<Product xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Adjustable Race</ProductName>
    <ProductNumber>AR-5381</ProductNumber>
    <ProductPrice>5.48</ProductPrice>
</Product>
```

It is giving a validation error.

> The element 'Product' in namespace
>   'http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010' has invalid
>   child element 'ProductID' in namespace
>   'http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice,
>   ProductNumber, ProductColor'.

Is the XML not formatted correctly?

Answer (score 1):

With your current schema, it is expecting each of the `Product` child elements not to be bound to a namespace.

If your intent was that all of the `Product` element children should be in the targetNamespace like the `Product` element, you need to indicate that they should be *qualified*. The default behavior is that they are *unqualified*.

You could specify on each element with the `default="qualified"` attribute:

```
<xs:element name="ProductColor" default="qualified" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
```

Or you can specify it globally on the `xs:schema` element with the `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
           xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
           xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="ProductColor" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
                <xs:element name="ProductID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="ProductName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="ProductNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="ProductPrice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```